# Positive / Negative and Look Ahead / Look Behind confusion?

Tags: ruby, regex

```
s = "some {text|in|braces} found"
```

To get the contents between braces

```
s.scan(/(?<={).*(?=})/) #=> ["text|in|braces"]
```

Now to get the contents that are not in braces, I tried

```
s.scan(/(?<!{).*(?!})/) #=> ["some {text|in|braces} found", ""]
```

Clearly I am missing something very important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second regular expression is looking for

- an arbitrary string ".*"
- that is not preceded by "{"
- that is not followed by "}"

which of course matches the whole string, since "some {text|in|braces} found" is neither preceded by a "{" nor followed by a "}".

Comment: What is then the right expression using look ahead/behind to get the content that are not in the braces?

Comment: Define "not in the braces". Do you want it to return "some  found"?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to escape special chars with \ ")(?{}".

You can solve this with 2 operations first of all you can islotale your parameter with this regex:

```
s  = s.gsub(/.*(\{.*\})  # => "text|in|braces"
s.scan(/\w+/) # => ["text", "in", "braces"]
```

or

```
s.gsub(/.*(\{.*\}).scan(/\w+/)  # => ["text", "in", "braces"]
```